# Laravel 5.8 Relaciones entre tablas - obtener información entre 4 tablas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy haciendo un sistema de comidas, donde cada comida puede tener muchos extras, y cada extra tiene un solo grupo de extras.

Tengo 4 tablas (foods, extra_foods, extras y extra_groups). Estoy en el modelo foods, donde estoy obteniendo los datos de los extras que tiene cada food, esto lo hago bien con:

```
public function extras()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Extra::class, 'extra_foods');
}
```

Aquí me enlaza la tabla foods (comidas) con sus extras, usando la tabla intermedia extra_foods, que contiene el food_id y extra_id. Esto es correcto y funciona bien. Obtengo todos los extras de cada comida.

El problema lo tengo en obtener los extra_groups, que deben aparecer agrupados, ósea que si un plato de comida tiene 5 extras, y estos 5 extras pertenece al mismo grupo o se repite el grupo, al final obtengo los grupos pero sin repetir.

No se como hacer la relación correctamente desde el modelo Foods, ya que este debe 1º obtener los extras (este paso lo tengo), pero ¿Cómo relaciono esos datos recogidos para obtener un listado de extra_groups?.

TABLAS

- FOODS: id
- EXTRA_FOODS: food_id, extra_id
- EXTRAS: id, extra_group_id
- EXTRA_GROUPS: id

Answer (score 0):

creo que según entiendo necesitas acceder entre relaciones de modelos.

Es decir:

- Tendrías que crear un modelo por cada tabla implicada (por convención los modelos se llaman en singular Foods → Food y las tablas en plural)
- Posteriormente creas una relación de cada modelo hacia los datos que requieres
- Por último lo llamarías así:

  $food->extras

Recuerda que tienes aquí una colección de elementos así que no puedes acceder a cada relación, tendrías que recorrerlos con un foreach y entonces accedes por cada elemento a su relación:

```
@foreach ($food->extras as $extra) {
   {{$extra->extraGroups}}
```

Esa sería la forma usando relaciones tal como yo las conozco.

En los casos así cuando quiero minimizar consultas (para relaciones tienes with de todas formas) creo una función en el modelo y hago directamente la consulta usando joins y seleccionando los campos que necesitare (usando el ORM siempre que puedo).

No sé si esto puede servirte de ayuda pero básicamente un modelo llama a otro.
Cuando son relaciones belongsTo se ve más claro, algo así $principal->rel1->rel2->rel3 pero en tu caso debes tener cuidado ya que es una colección y devuelve muchos resultados no accesibles directamente pero si recorriéndolos.

Creo que me he extendido demasiado y he dado muchos rodeos pero en resumen sería crear una relación más dentro de cada modelo final (en la tabla de join no hace falta en principio)

Answer (score 0):

Este es mi modelo Food, tiene muchos más métodos que hacen otras cosas. Aquí pongo como relaciono la tabla foods con la tabla intermedia extra_foods, y como enlaza el modelo Food con el modelo Extra. Como decía esta relación es perfecta y funciona bien.

El problema esta en el método extraGroups(), necesito obtener los grupos de lo extras, pero dependiente de los extras que obtengo en el método de arriba. Y todo esto quiero hacerlo en el modelo, no en el controlador.

Todo esto lo hago así por que llamo desde una API externa y llamo haciendo uso de "with".

**Modelo Food**

```
class Food extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    public function extras()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Extra::class, 'extra_foods');
    }

    public function extraGroups()
    {
    //EL PROBLEMA ESTA AQUI, NO SE COMO OBTENER LOS GRUPOS DE EXTRAS, QUE DEPENDEN DE LOS EXTRAS
    }
}
```

Había probado en hacer algo así, pero no funciona:

```
public function extraGroups()
    {
        $extras = $this->extras()->groupBy('extra_group_id');
        $extraGroups = [];
        foreach ($extras as $e) {
            array_push($extraGroups, \App\Models\ExtraGroup::find($e->extra_group_id));
        }
        return $extraGroups;
    }
```

Comment: Pues como te decía, creas esa relación extraGroups() dentro del modelo "Extra" ya que un conjunto se asocia a cada resultado que obtienes en el método "extras()"

Comment: Pero haciendo eso, me añade la información del grupo extra dentro del objeto extra, y eso no me vale. Yo necesito que desde el modelo Food, tener un listado de los grupos extras usados por los extras que tiene esa comida.

Comment: Para lograr la respuesta deseada la única forma que conozco usando relaciones es crear otra función más que llame a la relación "extras()" la recorrea y creas una colección o array asociando cada "Extra" con cada "ExtraGroup".

Por ello te decía que a veces es mejor crear una función y hacer una consulta con joins.

Por otro lado, si quieres que se devuelva todo con sus relaciones puedes añadir al modelo appends = ['allWithExtras'] a un atributo ej: "getAllWithExtrasAttribute(){ /*compones el resultado*/ }" así llevará todo en el json

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, pero no entiendo bien las relaciones en Laravel aún. Si miras el último ejemplo de método que he publicado extraGroups(), en esa prueba obtengo los extras de la comida, los recorro y obtengo el grupo de cada extra, pero no funciona....

Comment: Claro, eso no es por las relaciones sino un concepto de php: Intentas acceder a un método estático pero no lo es.

Esto no es estático: Food::extras()->groupBy('extra_group_id');
Tendrías que llamarlo así: $this->extras()->groupBy('extra_group_id');

Comment: Si, lo sé. Es lo primero que probé. Si hago return $this->extras()->groupBy('extra_group_id'); Devuelve bien, pero si guardo esa consulta en una variable para buscar su grupo, guardarlo en un array y devolverlo es donde esta el error.

Comment: Si miras el método extraGroups ahora verás que si esta bien, pero la llamada API no me devuelve nada.... si devuelvo directamente los extras entonces si va bien, es al momento de editar los resultados.

Comment: Pero tal como te decía desde el primer comentario y en los anteriores, a ver intento explicarlo de otra forma:
- Creas una relación en cada modelo.
- Creas una función getter "getNombreAttribute(){...}"
- Dentro del getter que estará en el modelo "Food" Accedes a $this->extras sin paréntesis
- Haces un foreach de $this->extras (agrupado o filtrado como necesites)
- En cada iteración, accedes a la relación por cada modelo "Extra" y compones un array o colección.
- El array compuesto lo devuelves en el return.
- En el modelo "Food" añades al array "$appends" el getter que acabas de crear